# Access navigation controller from start destination fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-jetpack

I am using the new navigation from android jetpack.
In my nav graph I got my LoginFragment as start destination and my MainActivity as host.
When I run the app the LoginFragment gets displayed. My question:

How can I navigate to other destinations from this fragment? I don't know how to access the navigation controller from a fragment.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The [Navigation component codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/#0) explains in details how to navigate between fragments.